# Is it possible to create a NGINX reverse proxy for a forward proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

One of our partners has a forward proxy server through which we can access specific services in their intranet. For example with curl like this: `curl --proxy 192.168.11.31:8080 https://service.intranet`

I now want to access `https://service.intranet` via a NGINX reverse proxy, for example like this: `http://nginx.mycompany/service`

I thought about something like this, but can't get it to work...

```
upstream remote-proxy { 
    server 192.168.11.31:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    location /service {
        proxy_pass https://service.intranet;
    }
}
```

Is this even possible with NGINX? If not, can you think about another solution? Thanks a lot!